# Angular select blinking

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple `<select></select>` inside a `<div>` with a `ng-show` attribute, something like:

```
<div ng-show="edit">
  <select ng-options="key as value in VALUES"></select>
</div>
```

Now for some reason, when I click on the `select` to open it, it will be blinking like if the select was opening/closing really quickly. Sometimes it blinks twice, sometimes more. I have used `select` boxes with angular before and never had this.

I found out what was causing it. The complete form where it happens looks like:

```
<form class="mb-lg" name="formValidate" ng-init="addCreate = '.action_add'" novalidate="" role="form">
  <label class="radio-inline c-radio">
    <input id="action_add" name="add_create" ng-model="addCreate" required="required" type="radio" value=".action_add">
    <span class="fa fa-circle"></span>
    Add to existing
  </label>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <select class="form-control" name="selected" ng-disabled="addCreate != '.action_add'" ng-model="selected" ng-options="p as p.name for p in portfolios | filter : {'update?': true}" ng-required="addCreate == '.action_add'" required="required"></select>
  </div>
  <label class="radio-inline c-radio ng-binding">
    <input id="action_create" name="add_create" ng-model="addCreate" required="required" type="radio" value=".action_create">
      <span class="fa fa-circle"></span>
      Or Create new one
  </label>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input class="form-control" name="name" ng-disabled="addCreate != '.action_create'" ng-model="new" ng-required="addCreate == '.action_create'" disabled="disabled">
  </div>
</form>
```

When the form is displayed, the first `<input>` (the selected radio button) is focused, and when I click on the `<select>` to open it, an `$apply` will occur (this is the basic behavior of Angular, nothing custom) causing the `<select>` to recompile? If I click anywhere, then the `<select>` will not blink, or it I blur it manually like `$(':focus').blur();` then it does not blink either.

Note: the form is in a dialog (`ngDialog`), not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: Something unusual. Demo please or it's hard to guess.

Comment: @dfsq yeah I know that's also why it's hard to create a plunkr or something... I hope someone would have the same problem ^^, and I will work on trying to reproduce

Comment: @dfsq I updated the description with a more complete example and my findings so far. I have tried putting it in a plunker but to no avail, the bug doesn't appear either

Comment: Actually, I only get a similar problem on my Chrome 50 on Mac, not my Windows. May I know if this applies to you also?

Comment: @IvorZhou yeah I am testing on Chrome 50/Mac, haven't tested any other browsers I must say

Comment: @Guillaume The problem only occurs for me on Chrome 50/Mac. Not on Chrome 50/Win nor Firefox / Safari / Edge

Comment: having the same issue on Chrome 50/Mac

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be this bug:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=613885

As suggested in the comments, setting transition to none on the select has worked around the problem, in my case (with bootstrap) using the following:

```
select.form-control { transition: none; }
```

For use without bootstrap, or where not using the .form-control class, simply drop the .form-control selector and make sure nothing else is overriding the transition property on select elements:

```
select { transition: none; }
```

Comment: Nice catch, I had to set it using `transition: none !important;` but it does fix the problem!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be fixed with Chrome release of 51.0.2704.63